# Find The Duplicate value in CouchDb

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I want to find same value in CouchDB. My Map is

```
function(doc) {
    var user = [];
if(doc.type = 'user'){
   user.push(doc.name);
    emit( doc.type, user);
  }
}
```

And I have the results like

```
["Bob"],["Peter"],["Bob"] ....
```

I'd Like to Have a reduce like

```
["Bob","Peter","Bob"]
```

Or an Array with only duplicate

```
["Bob","Bob"]
```

I don't understand How reduce works.
foreach value reduce is called or only when the map is finished?

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have the following three documents.

Bob:

```
{
  "_id": "89d9ffe10a33df504ecc8d7c9a975eed",
  "_rev": "1-dfc3128d8d80760f2cf40328dd24553e",
  "type": "user",
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

Peter:

```
{
  "_id": "89d9ffe10a33df504ecc8d7c9a98a0c6",
  "_rev": "1-820e231c44f9b3125db79e0c00bbc050",
  "type": "user",
  "name": "Peter"
}
```

Another Bob:

```
{
  "_id": "89d9ffe10a33df504ecc8d7c9a99f360",
  "_rev": "1-dfc3128d8d80760f2cf40328dd24553e",
  "type": "user",
  "name": "Bob"
}
```

You want to find documents with duplicate `name` values. Simply create a view on the `name` field with the following map function:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type == "user") {
    emit(doc.name);
  }
}
```

Use the built in `_count` reduce function. If you query this view with `reduce=false`, you will get the following results:

```
{
  total_rows: 3,
  offset: 0,
  rows: [
    {
      id: "89d9ffe10a33df504ecc8d7c9a975eed",
      key: "Bob",
      value: null
    },
    {
      id: "89d9ffe10a33df504ecc8d7c9a99f360",
      key: "Bob",
      value: null
    },
    {
      id: "89d9ffe10a33df504ecc8d7c9a98a0c6",
      key: "Peter",
      value: null
    }
  ]
}
```

As these results are collated (sorted) by `name`, duplicate `name` values will be adjacent to each other in the results.

Alternatively, you can query this view with `group=true` and you will get the following results:

```
{
  rows: [
    {
      key: "Bob",
      value: 2
    },
    {
      key: "Peter",
      value: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Any result with a `value` of `2` or greater indicates that there are duplicates. Having identified that there are duplicate entries for the key of `"Bob"`, you can then query for all of the `"Bob"`s using `reduce=false&key="Bob"`, which will give you the following results:

```
{
  total_rows: 3,
  offset: 1,
  rows: [
    {
      id: "89d9ffe10a33df504ecc8d7c9a975eed",
      key: "Bob",
      value: null
    },
    {
      id: "89d9ffe10a33df504ecc8d7c9a99f360",
      key: "Bob",
      value: null
    }
  ]
}
```