# How to remove duplicated entries from couchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am very new in couchDB. I have a problem with duplicated entries in my CouchDB database.

In order to solve it I have been reading this:
[Find The Duplicate value in CouchDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812501/find-the-duplicate-value-in-couchdb)
and it is very usuful.

To find duplicates entries I do in `Futon`:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.ismaster == true && doc.type == "article_aux"){  
        emit([doc.type,doc.id, doc.id_group], doc);
    }
}
```

On `Reduce Function` I have

> _count

So a duplicated documents has the same `id` and the same `id_group`.
Here you can see an example about the duplicated entries
[image]

This is the `Json` document structure for one document:

```
{
   "_id": "013684e1d7da89c1b290666a957fd4ce",
   "_rev": "1-c5f41865f78f0806c8df450794edeb1f",
   "type": "article_aux",
   "id": 1661,
   "name": "STEWARTIA SP",
   "security_time": 0,
   "id_reason_type": 0,
   "id_reason": 4,
   "id_group": 3,
   "dose": 2,
   "id_unit_dose": 406,
   "version": "0x000000004821A25D",
   "ismaster": true
}
```

The field `version` is an timestamp

The problem I have is I dont know how to remove the duplicated entries.

Comment: First thing you should ask yourself is why is there so much duplicates? Is that intended? If not, fix it. Otherwise, to remove duplicates, you probably want to query all of them. Then, you either want to merge the different versions together to keep the changes or keep the latest one. Then, remove all the other revisions.

Comment: thanks @AlexisCôté is a project develop for  other people, I know where is the issue and how to fix it, but first I have to removes all the duplicated document . I wantto keep just one document, the last revision . Remove all the other revions....that is the point ...how?

Comment: Do you have any document properties that mark the document with a tiomestamp?

Comment: @AlexisCôté yes I have something similar , I am going to add my document json structure in my question tomorrow morning